# Sprite Kit: SKSpriteNode controlled by device motion falls out of the screen in the corners

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, core-motion, skspritenode

I am creating a SpriteKit game which uses the CoreMotion framework to move a SKSpriteNode, `userNode`, around the screen. For the scaling, I have set it to ResizeFill, and have used view.frame to store the four bounds of the view in variables:

```
//setting screens bounds
    var rightBound = CGFloat()
    var leftBound = CGFloat()
    var upperBound = CGFloat()
    var bottomBound = CGFloat()
    rightBound = view.frame.width - (userNode.size.width / 2)
    leftBound = CGRectGetMinX(view.frame) + (userNode.size.width / 2)
    upperBound = view.frame.height - (userNode.size.height / 2)
    bottomBound = CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + (userNode.size.height / 2)
```

To attempt to keep `userNode` on screen, I created a function to run in the update function:

```
func keepUserNodeOnScreen(){
    if userNode.position.x >= rightBound{
        userNode.position.x = rightBound

    }
    else if userNode.position.x <= leftBound{
        userNode.position.x = leftBound
    }
    else if userNode.position.y >= upperBound{
        userNode.position.y = upperBound
    }
    else if userNode.position.y <= bottomBound{
        userNode.position.y = bottomBound
    }

}
```

For some reason, however, when the node reaches the corners of the view, it falls out of the view. I have also tried `self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect(view.frame))`, but this didn't work either. What could it be that is causing this?

Edit:
Here is the userNode generation code:

```
    userNode.color = SKColor.redColor()
    userNode.size = CGSizeMake(15, 15)
    userNode.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height / 2)
    userNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: userNode.size)
    userNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    userNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    userNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = userCategory
    userNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bulletCategory
    self.addChild(userNode)
```

Here is the code for moving `userNode`, set to run in the update function:

```
func moveUserNode(){
    if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true{
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.001

        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler:{
            deviceManager, error in
            if self.gameOn == true{
                var roll: CGFloat = CGFloat(self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll)
                var pitch: CGFloat = CGFloat(-self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch) + CGFloat(0.6)

                //Keep userNode on screen

                self.newPosition.x = self.userNode.position.x + CGFloat(roll) * 20
                self.newPosition.y = self.userNode.position.y + CGFloat(pitch) * 20
                self.userNode.position = self.newPosition

            }
            else if self.gameOn == false{
                self.motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code that creates the borders and the usernode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `keepUserNodeOnScreen`, your `if/else` statements aren't testing for all the possible ways `userNode` can exit the screen. Deleting all of the `else` statements will resolve this.

An alternative approach is to add an edge-loop

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect(view.frame))
```

and move `userNode` with `applyForce` or `applyImpulse` instead of moving it by changing its position property. SpriteKit does not detect collisions if the node's position is changed, directly.

Comment: Removing the else statements worked! Thanks. I'll keep the other fix in mind for a later project.